# How do you loop through the models in the yii framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I am trying to loop through the names of my model files in yii so I can auto populate a link system in my admin section. Basically if I go to the Gii generator and create a new CRUD section, I want it to take the model name and add a link to that certain CRUD home page.

This is what i have so far on my admin home page:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/admin/company">Edit Company Information</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/admin/gallery">Edit Gallery</a></li>
```

so what i would just change the "company" and "gallery" names into a variable that grabs the names of the model and loop through this, question is how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [CFileHelper::findFiles()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileHelper) in order to get the contents of your models folder,

```
$filenames =CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::getPathOfAlias("application.models"), array ( 
    'fileTypes'=> array('.php'),
  )
);
```

Next up you can apply a filter to the results, so you exclude these models which possibly have nothing to do with the purpose of your designed model list.

```
$modelNames = array();
foreach ($filenames as $filename)
{
  //remove off the path
  $file = end( explode( '/', $filename ) );
  // remove the extension, strlen('.php') = 4
  $file = substr( $file, 0, strlen($file) - 4);
  $modelNames[]=$file
}
//$modelNames holds all the names of the model files without paths or extensions.
```

Comment: This way got me on the right path. This is how i solved it: in my controller i wrapped the top code in a function, changed the path to the models I was looking for, also had to change `.php` to just `php`; then i wrote this script in the views `<?php $filenames = $this->links(); ?> <?php foreach($filenames as $key => $file): ?>
        <?php $info = pathinfo($file);?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/admin/<?php echo $info['filename'];?>">Edit <?php echo $info['filename'];?></a></li>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>` and now it works perfectly, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can propose the following.

First, you create a basic model (for example, in `components` directory) your other models will be derived from:

```
class BaseModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function getAdminRoute()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Static `getAdminRoute` method will provide an Yii route to administrative page of a model. And you extend `BaseModel` like this:

```
class Company extends BaseModel
{
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return "{{company}}";
    }

    public static function getAdminRoute()
    {
        return "admin/company";
    }
}
```

The next step is to deretmine all models that are declared in your application:

```
$models = array();
$modelsDir = Yii::getPathOfAlias("application.models");
$dh = opendir($modelsDir);
if ($dh !== false)
{
    $matches = array();
    while (($modelFileName = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {
        if (preg_match("/^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.php$/", $modelFileName, $matches))
            array_push($models, $matches[1]);
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

After a list of model classes retrieved (according to Yii naming convention file's name is equal to its class' name) you can iterate over it and get administrative links for those models that have overriden `getAdminRoute` method:

```
$adminLinks = array();
foreach($models as $model)
{
    if (method_exists($model, "getAdminPage"))
    {
        $modelAdminRoute = $model::getAdminPage();
        if ($modelAdminRoute !== null)
            array_push($adminLinks, Yii::app()->createUrl($modelAdminRoute));
    }
}
```

Of course, you can omit `admin` part in `getAdminRoute` and implement this method in your own taste and add an additional method to get link's text.

For performance reasons you also can try to cache obtained list of administrative links using [caching features provided by Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.0/en/caching.data).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i just have a couple questions. (New to Yii) what file to i put the "class Company extends BaseModel" script in and same goes for the bottom two scripts? i also placed the BaseModel in the componets folder as you suggested. Also my admin folder is palced inside the modules folder. (if that helps)

Comment: You put `class Company extends BaseModel` to `models/Company.php` file of your application. `models` directory is where your model classes are stored by default. You can also merge two bottom scripts together and place them in some `controllers/AdminController.php` file as `AdminController` class' method that you will call each time when you need to prepare admin links for a view.

Comment: By the way, I wrote code snippets supposing that used `components`, `contollers` and `models` are located in application's `protected` directory. If you use a module to organize your cotrollers and models then everything works for modules too - you need to modify corresponding paths only: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module